# Is it possible to rent an apartment monthly in EU, non-EU citizen

Tags: legal, tourist-visas, eu, rental

I am a Russian citizen who has a 3 years EU multi visa category `C`. 
I would like to **legally** rent an apartment in EU with a monthly payment for a long term, 2+ months. The idea is that I will be leaving and coming back to this potential apartment. Is it possible?

Comment: Which country in EU?

Comment: I'm doing it right now. I'm a non-EU citizen, renting for 3 months in the EU. AFAIK it's 100% legal, I didn't consult a lawyer though.

Comment: @Kuba Lithuania

Comment: EU law says nothing about it. National law in a specific country might have restrictions but the main hurdle is probably landlords. Checking whether you are a resident isn't necessarily mandatory but they might favour residents for all sorts of reasons. That's assuming you are looking at 6+ months and hoping to get the lower long-term rental price. Renting a holiday home for 2 or 3 months should in any case be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about Germany, short-term rental in hotels or holiday apartments and long-term rental of an apartment are different market segments, with different regulations in some areas.

- Most landlords will do some financial background checks of their tenant. You might come up empty on the [most common check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schufa), which makes you appear as a "high-risk" tenant.
- People are required to register with the municipal authorities in their place of residence. A hotel takes care of this for the guest, a landlord does not.
- Tenants have to enter an individual contract with a power company, with readings of the meter when they move in or leave.

So even if there is no law against it, it might be impractical for just a few months. [Subletting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lease#Sublease) might be more practical.